# asp.net inserting image into database via ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I can insert images into database or display them in the Image Control and so on but I would like to insert them into database via ListView. I achieved that partially. During I insert a new item, I browse an image via FileUpload Control "FileUploadMedical" and insert it into database via "MedicalUploadButton" (You can see its code behind below). I want to get rid of that MedicalUploadButton and use default ListView "Insert" and "Edit" buttons. I should probably keep "FileUpload" control in order to browse the image. Below is what I have done sofar.

Normally I display an image in listview via a ImageHandler.ashx and display the image at the ItemTemplate as below;

```
   <ItemTemplate >
         <tr style="">
             <td>
                 <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                 <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
             </td>
             <td>
                <asp:Image ID="MedicalImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?ID="+Eval("MedicalID")+"&Entity=Medical"%>'/>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

It works perfectly.

This is how I insert the image into listview;

```
        <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadMedical" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="MedicalUploadButton" runat="server" text="Hoch Laden" OnClick="MedicalUploadButton_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind of the button MedicalUploadButton

```
       protected void MedicalUploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload Fupload = (FileUpload)AdminListView.EditItem.FindControl("FileUploadMedical");
        if (Fupload.HasFile)
        {
            string FilePath = Fupload.PostedFile.FileName;
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            string ContentType = String.Empty;

            switch (Ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".jpeg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    ContentType = "Image/png";
                    break;
                case ".bmp":
                    ContentType = "Image/bmp";
                    break;
            }

            if (ContentType != String.Empty)
            {
                Stream FileStream = Fupload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader FileReader = new BinaryReader(FileStream);
                Byte[] bytes = FileReader.ReadBytes((Int32)FileStream.Length);

                //double check and make sure that this is getting the correct item
                ListViewItem commentItem = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;

                if (commentItem != null)
                {
                    //instead of using the DisplayIndex use the DataItemIndex
                    int medID = (int)AdminListView.DataKeys[commentItem.DataItemIndex]["MedicalID"];

                    //insert the file into database
                    using (Entity.MedicalEntities emp = new Entity.MedicalEntities())
                    {

                        Entity.Medical medicals = (from h in emp.Medicals where h.MedicalID == medID select h).First();
                        medicals.MedicalImage = bytes;
                        emp.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is actually pretty straight forward and works perfectly but at the InsertItemTemplate or EditItemTemplate I don't want to use my custom MedicalUploadButton_Click function but I just want to use that "MedicalUpload" FileUpload control, browse image then click Insert or Edit and image should be inserted into database.

So to be more precise I want to delete that MedicalUploadButton_Click function and use default "Insert" and "Edit" buttons of the listview in order to insert the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after some researchs. First of all we have to add the following events to listview;

```
OnItemUpdating="DistrictList_ItemUpdating" OnItemInserted="DistrictList_ItemInserted"
```

At the code behind of DistrictList_ItemUpdating (for the Edit command)you can add the following;

```
        protected void DistrictList_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload Fupload = (FileUpload)DistrictList.EditItem.FindControl("FileUploadDistrictEdit");
        if (Fupload.HasFile)
        {
            string FilePath = Fupload.PostedFile.FileName;
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            string ContentType = String.Empty;



            switch (Ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".jpeg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    ContentType = "Image/png";
                    break;
                case ".bmp":
                    ContentType = "Image/bmp";
                    break;
            }

            if (ContentType != String.Empty)
            {
                Stream FileStream = Fupload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader FileReader = new BinaryReader(FileStream);
                Byte[] bytes = FileReader.ReadBytes((Int32)FileStream.Length);

                string disName = e.NewValues["DistrictName"].ToString(); 

                //insert the file into database
                using (Entity.MedicalEntities emp = new Entity.MedicalEntities())
                {

                    Entity.District districts = (from h in emp.Districts where h.DistrictName == disName select h).First();
                    districts.DistrictImage = bytes;
                    emp.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For the updating part for me the most important part is the following line. Getting the DistrictName value of the editing row of the listview;

```
 string disName = e.NewValues["DistrictName"].ToString();
```

And for the Insert command, you can add the following. I use "Inserted" command for it. Get the "DistrictName" of the newly added "District" record and use it at the Where claus of the linq.

```
protected void DistrictList_ItemInserted(object sender, ListViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload Fupload = (FileUpload)DistrictList.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUploadDistrictInsert");
        if (Fupload.HasFile)
        {
            string FilePath = Fupload.PostedFile.FileName;
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            string Ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            string ContentType = String.Empty;



            switch (Ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".JPG":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".jpeg":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
                    break;
                case ".JPEG":
                    ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    ContentType = "Image/png";
                    break;
                case ".PNG":
                    ContentType = "Image/png";
                    break;
                case ".bmp":
                    ContentType = "Image/bmp";
                    break;
                case ".BMP":
                    ContentType = "Image/bmp";
                    break;
            }

            if (ContentType != String.Empty)
            {
                Stream FileStream = Fupload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader FileReader = new BinaryReader(FileStream);
                Byte[] bytes = FileReader.ReadBytes((Int32)FileStream.Length);

                string disID = e.Values["DistrictName"].ToString();

                //insert the file into database
                using (Entity.MedicalEntities emp = new Entity.MedicalEntities())
                {

                    Entity.District districts = (from h in emp.Districts where h.DistrictName == disID select h).First();
                    districts.DistrictImage = bytes;
                    emp.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And again for me the most important part of it is the following line to get the "DistrictName" of the newly created record;

```
 string disID = e.Values["DistrictName"].ToString();
```

If you have any suggestions or find any drawback please let me know.